# Text color overrides link color

Tags: hyperref, color

I am trying to change the color of all the text in the report, while customizing the colors of the links. My aim is to have all text in blue and the links colored in red (not the box around the links, but the link). The end result for now is: everything is blue.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks, allcolors=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{soul}

\setmainfont{Arial}[Color = blue]
\setulcolor{uocblue}

\hypersetup{
    linktocpage=true,
    allcolors=red
}
\urlstyle{same}
\color{blue}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{one chapter}\label{a}
    
    here is a reference to \nameref{a}
\end{document}
```

Comment: font colors always win, you can change them with color commands.

Comment: As commented by @UlrikeFischer If you remove the `[Color = blue]` when loading the font, it works. Although I would put the `\color{blue}` *after* `\begin{document}` (not sure about this).

Comment: I meant "you can't change them".

Comment: @Rmano it worked! i put the `\color{blue}` linea before the `\begin{document}`, removed the `[Color = blue]` and ta-dah! Thank you very much!

Comment: plazarotello yes, that was the meaning of @UlrikeFischer comment....